# What do the various beers do?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

Some of the beer choices in Deep Rock Galactic have crazy effects like freezing your dwarf, giving you double vision, or explosive gas that launches you around the space rig. Others seem to have no effect at all. They can be a bit pricey to unlock, so I'd like to know what effects the different beers have.

What does each beer do?

Answer (score 14):

The most important beers for every hard working dwarf are present in **Today's Specials** section. Only one of them is available at any time after this menu's section initially unlocked, but their effect lasts for the entire next mission (or for the entire Deep Dive). There are 8 Special Beers:

| Name | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| Backbreaker Stout | ×1.3225 Carry Movement Speed |
| Dark Morkite | x1.44 Morkite Mined |
| Pots O' Gold | x4 Gold Mined |
| Red Rock Blaster | x1.69 Max Health |
| Rocky Mountain | -2 Pickaxe Hit per Terrain |
| Skull Crusher Ale | +20 Pickaxe Damage |
| Slayer Stout | x0.25 Pickaxe Power Attack Recharge Rate |
| Tunnel Rat | -60% Fall Damage |

**Regular Beers** are always available and don't require Beer License:

| Name | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| Oily Oaf Brew | - |
| Glyphid Slammer | - |
| Leaf Lover's Special | Removes Drunk status effect |

**Craft Beers** require unlocking by purchasing Beer License and they provide some additional effects but only in Space Rig. There are 13 Craft Beers:

| Name | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| Arkenstout | A harsh blizzard freezes the player, encasing them in ice |
| Blacklock Lager | The player experiences nightmarish hallucinations of ghosts |
| Blackout Stout | Increases drunkenness to max, causing the player to pass out |
| Blackreach Blonde | The player receives the Jukebox effect and starts dancing |
| Burning Love | The player catches on fire |
| Flintlocke's Delight | Explosions occur around the player, propelling them in random directions |
| Gut Wrecker | The player releases a loud burp, shaking their screen |
| Mactera Brew | Player releases a loud fart, creating a green cloud around them |
| Malt Rockbearer | The player grows in size |
| Seasoned Moonrider | The player recieves low gravity, and gains an upward boost in momentum |
| Smart Stout | The player becomes temporarily intelligent and talks like a scientist |
| Underhill Deluxe | The player shrinks in size |
| Wormhole Special | Teleports the player to a random location (either inside the Drop Pod or outside the Space Rig.) |

Source (which has much better formatting and also icons) https://deeprockgalactic.gamepedia.com/Abyss_Bar